# How to get started with RavenDB.AspNetHost package?

Tags: asp.net, ravendb, ravendb-studio

how to use and configure the RavenDB.AspNetHost package from NuGet?

I added it to ma empty ASP.NET 4.5 WebApplication project, and this package is adding a connection string `<add name="RavenDB" connectionString="Url=http://localhost:8080" />` to my webconfig.

But when starting the project (running with VS2012 + IIS Express) it is not listening on port 8080. Also a DocumentSession from the same ASP.NET App cannot connect to the server.

How to access the studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using AspNetHost, you host RavenDB in a ASP.NET / IIS
You access it via the url that the project gives you.